# How to find the parametric equations for the line through the point that is parallel to the plane.

Tags: vectors, parametric, skew-symmetric-matrices

How to find the equations of the line passing through the point $(8, 7, 9)$, intersecting the $z$-axis and parallel to the plane $2x−6y+z−12=0$.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @dumb005 If you do not share your own attempts on solving the problem your post will be most likely closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
Let $A(8,7,9)$ and $M(0,0,z)$ the intersection of the sought line with the $z$. If you determine $M$, the parametric equation will follow.

The line $AM$ is parallel to the plane if and only if $\vec{AM}$ is orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane $\vec n\,(2,-6,1)$.